# Портится двумерный массив в СИ

Tags: c, массивы

По сути простейший код, отдельная функция. Суть в том, что из функции (str[size]) последовательно выделяются элементы в скобках, а затем записываются в двумерный массив (вообще, в финальной версии должен быть трехмерный, но не суть). То есть в данном случае в массив tmpy должны записаться 2 строки:

- "6-(5-1)"
- "5-1"

Нулевая строчка записывается верно, все штатно, но после записи 1й строки - нулевая портится, туда записывается часть 1й. По идее зло таится в 56 строке. Уже 3й день сижу  с этим, буду очень благодарен помоще!

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define size 15
int main ()
{
   char str [size]="4-4(6-(5-1))";
   char *istr[5], *istrr[5];
   char zn[2];
   char tmpy[size][5];

   int i, j=0, k = 0, a=0, b=0, sch=0, tmp[3];
    zn[0] = '(';
    zn[1] = ')';
    memset(tmpy, ' ', sizeof(tmpy));
   printf("%s\n", str);

do
{
    a=0;
    b=0;
    b=0;
    tmp[2]=j;
    for (i=0;i<size; i++) //узнали номер первой открывающей скобки
        if (str[i]==zn[0])
        {
            tmp[0] = i;
            i=size;
        }
                i = tmp[0];
    do// узанли адреса всех открывающих и закрывающих скобок одной части
    {
        if (str[i]==zn[0])
        {
            istr[a] = &str[i];
            a++;
            sch++;
        }
        else if (str[i]==zn[1])
        {
            istrr[b] = &str[i];
            b++;
            sch--;
            if (sch==0)
                {tmp[1]=i;}
        }
        i++;
    }
    while(sch!=0);

printf("\nso, there string is:\n");

    k=0;
for(i=tmp[0]+1;i<tmp[1]; i++)
{
    tmpy[j][k] = str[i];
    k++;
}
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
            printf("%c", tmpy[j][i]);
        printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        str[i]=tmpy[j][i];

j++;
a--;
}
while (a!=0);

printf("\n\n still alive\n\n");
for (j=0; j<tmp[2]+1; j++)
    {
        printf("%d||| ", j);
        for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%c",tmpy[j][i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то у меня подозрение, что вы хотели на `char tmpy[size][5];`, а `char tmpy[5][size];`. У вас точно все строки (`size` штук) не длиннее 4 символов?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявите не `size` строк по 5 символов (включая нулевой)

```
   char tmpy[size][5];
```

а 5 строк по `size` символов:

```
   char tmpy[5][size];
```

Comment: Как всегда глупая ошибка в начале, огромное спасибо!

Comment: Ну, если ответ устроил - помечайте, как принятый...